# Starting a thread for each inner loop in OpenMP

Tags: c, arrays, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm fairly new to OpenMP and I'm trying to start an individual thread to process each item in a 2D array.

So essentially, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
        a[i][j] = b[i][j] + c[i][j];
```

What I'm doing is this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(a,b,c) private(i,j) reduction(+:diff) schedule(dynamic)
    for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            a[i][j] = b[i][j] + c[i][j];
```

Does this in fact start a thread for each 2D item or no?  How would I test that?  If it is wrong, what is the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Note: The code has been greatly simplified

Comment: Might want to tag it with the language you're using, although you'd have to remove one of the existing tags.

Comment: Good point mmyers - for reference it looks like he is using c/c++ (openMP is c/c++ and fortran only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the outer loop is parallel in your code sample. You can test by printing `omp_get_thread_num()` in the inner loop and you will see that, for a given `i`, the thread num is the same (of course, this test is demonstrative rather than definitive since different runs will give different results). For example, with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define dimension 4

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
            printf("i=%d, j=%d, thread = %d\n", i, j, omp_get_thread_num());
    }
```

I get:

```
i=1, j=0, thread = 1
i=3, j=0, thread = 3
i=2, j=0, thread = 2
i=0, j=0, thread = 0
i=1, j=1, thread = 1
i=3, j=1, thread = 3
i=2, j=1, thread = 2
i=0, j=1, thread = 0
i=1, j=2, thread = 1
i=3, j=2, thread = 3
i=2, j=2, thread = 2
i=0, j=2, thread = 0
i=1, j=3, thread = 1
i=3, j=3, thread = 3
i=2, j=3, thread = 2
i=0, j=3, thread = 0
```

As for the rest of your code, you might want to put more details in a new question (it's difficult to tell from the small sample), but for example, you can't put `private(j)` when `j` is only declared later. It is automatically private in my example above. I guess `diff` is a variable that we can't see in the sample. Also, the loop variable `i` is automatically  private (from the [version 2.5 spec](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec25.pdf) - same in the 3.0 spec)

> The loop iteration variable in the
>   for-loop of a for or parallel for
>   construct is private in that
>   construct.

Edit: All of the above is correct for the code that you and I have shown, but you may be interested in the following. For OpenMP Version 3.0 (available in e.g. [gcc version 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html), but not version 4.3) there is a `collapse` clause where you could write the code as you have, but with 
`#pragma omp parallel for collapse (2)` to parallelize both for loops (see [the spec](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf)).

**Edit**: OK, I downloaded gcc 4.5.0 and ran the above code, but using `collapse (2)` to get the following output, showing the inner loop now parallelized:

```
i=0, j=0, thread = 0
i=0, j=2, thread = 1
i=1, j=0, thread = 2
i=2, j=0, thread = 4
i=0, j=1, thread = 0
i=1, j=2, thread = 3
i=3, j=0, thread = 6
i=2, j=2, thread = 5
i=3, j=2, thread = 7
i=0, j=3, thread = 1
i=1, j=1, thread = 2
i=2, j=1, thread = 4
i=1, j=3, thread = 3
i=3, j=1, thread = 6
i=2, j=3, thread = 5
i=3, j=3, thread = 7
```

Comments [here](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopDirectiveFor) (search for "Workarounds") are also relevant for work-arounds in version 2.5 if you want to parallelize both loops, but the version 2.5 spec cited above is quite explicit (see the non-conforming examples in section [A.35](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec25.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try of using nested omp parallel fors (after `omp_set_nested(1)` call), but they a not supported on all openmp implementations.

So I guess to make some 2D grid and start all thread on grid from single for (example for fixed 4x4 thread grid):

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(k = 0; k < 16; k++)
{
    int i,j,i_min,j_min,i_max,j_max;
    i_min=(k/4) * (dimension/4);
    i_max=(k/4 + 1) * (dimension/4);
    j_min=(k%4) * (dimension/4);
    j_max=(k%4 + 1) * (dimension/4);

    for(i=i_min;i<i_max;i++)
      for(j=j_min;j<j_max;j++)
       f(i,j);

}
```