# Compiling using GSL and OpenMP

Tags: gcc, openmp, gsl

I am not the best when it comes to compiling/writing makefiles.

I am trying to write a program that uses both GSL and OpenMP.

I have no problem using GSL and OpenMP separately, but I'm having issues using both.  For instance, I can compile the GSL program
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/An-Example-Program.html
By typing

```
$gcc -c Bessel.c
$gcc Bessel.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
$./a.out
```

and it works.

I was also able to compile the program that uses OpenMP that I found here:
[Starting a thread for each inner loop in OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215818/starting-a-thread-for-each-inner-loop-in-openmp)

In this case I typed

```
$gcc -fopenmp test_omp.c
$./a.out
```

And I got what I wanted (all 4 threads I have were used).

However, when I simply write a program that combines the two codes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
#include <omp.h> 

 int
 main (void)
 {
   double x = 5.0;
   double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
   printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);


int dimension = 4;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
#pragma omp parallel private(i, j)
for (i =0; i < dimension; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        printf("i=%d, jjj=%d, thread = %d\n", i, j, omp_get_thread_num());

return 0;

 }
```

Then I try to compile to typing

```
$gcc -c Bessel_omp_test.c
$gcc Bessel_omp_test.o -fopenmp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
$./a.out
```

The GSL part works (The Bessel function is computed), but only one thread is used for the OpenMP part.  I'm not sure what's wrong here...

Comment: Because user1202136 pointed out a mistake I made in my original code, I've corrected that in an edit.  I am still having the same problem though.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the worksharing directive `for` in your OpenMP part. It should be:

```
// Just in case GSL modifies the number of threads
omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());
omp_set_dynamic(0);

#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
for (i =0; i < dimension; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        printf("i=%d, jjj=%d, thread = %d\n", i, j, omp_get_thread_num());
```

Edit: To summarise the discussion in the comments below, the OP failed to supply `-fopenmp` during the compilation phase. That prevented GCC from recognising the OpenMP directives and thus no paralle code was generated.

Comment: That did not work either.  If I run the above code and delete the GSL part to compute the Bessel function, it works when I compile using $gcc -fopenmp omp_test.c.

However, when I use GSL and try to compile by what I described above, only 1 thread was used.  It seems to be purely an issue of compiling syntax

Comment: Still does not work.  I think it has something to do with what I'm typing into the command prompt when compiling...see the end of my original post

Comment: Note that if I write a program that only does the code you wrote above, but does not do the small GSL computation, then I can compile using: $gcc -fopenmp omp_test.c.  However, when I use GSL I need to link all the libraries properly, and what I tried was the three lines in my original post, but that did not work

Comment: If the OpenMP library is not linked properly, you'd get undefined symbols for all `omp_*` functions. Try also to prevent dynamic changes in the number of OpenMP threads. Put this after `omp_set_num_threads` call: `omp_set_dynamic(0);`. I don't know what GSL does with the OpenMP runtime. That's why I am suggesting all this.

Comment: Still not working.  Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that when I link OpenMP I use "-f" and for GSL it is "-l" (Not sure if this is a silly question, but note the first sentence of my post:  "I am not the best when it comes to compiling/writing makefiles.")

Comment: `-llib` links the library `liblib.so` or `liblib.a` to your program. `-fopenmp` is a compiler directive that enables OpenMP support in GCC. These are different things and your are doing it right, at least for the compilation/linking part.

Comment: Somehow, what I just mentioned must be the problem.  Even if I try to compile the program and delete the GSL part using $gcc -c opm_test.c $gcc omp_test.o -fopenmp $./aout only 1 thread is used, but if I do a simple 2 step compilation process $gcc -fopenmp omp_test.c $./a.out it works...however, I don't know how to compile using the GSL library without doing a more complicated three step compilation process like $gcc -c Bessel.c $gcc Bessel.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm $./aout

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem...If I try to compile using $gcc -fopenmp -c Bessel_omp_test.c $gcc Bessel_omp_test.o -fopenmp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm $./a.out, then it works (Note the additional -fopenmp in the first step of compiling)...Also, this same template template worked in my more complicated code mixing GSL and OpenMP that I was originally interested in (I used "top" in a terminal and saw about 400% CPU usage)

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I see the missing `-fopenmp` during the compilation phase too :)

Comment: Do you know why I should include `-fopenmp` there as well...I basically took a guess...

Comment: Because you must enable OpenMP support while the source file is being compiled, otherwise the compiler would just ignore all OpenMP directives and no parallel code would be generated. Intel's `icc` compiler gives you warnings of unrecognised pragmas if you compile OpenMP code without OpenMP support enabled. `gcc` apparently does not.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's incorrect to declare the variables `i` and `j` as shared. Try declaring them private. Otherwise, each thread would get the same `j` and `j++` would generate a race condition among threads.